# Ember test failing

Tags: ember.js

I'm running 'ember test --server' on my application and I get two failures and I'm not sure why they're failing.

From the CLI:

```
> ToUrlHelper: it works
>     ✘ Died on test #1     at eval (new-cms/tests/unit/helpers/to-url-test.js:10:5)
>         at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:70:29)
>         at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:14:29: undefined is not a function
```

From the web browser:

```
> Died on test #1     at eval
> (new-cms/tests/unit/helpers/to-url-test.js:10:5)
>     at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:70:29)
>     at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:14:29: undefined is not a function Source:      TypeError: undefined is not a function
>     at Object.eval (new-cms/tests/unit/helpers/to-url-test.js:11:20)
>     at Object.Test.run (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1078:18)
>     at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1165:10
>     at process (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:881:24)
>     at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:470:5
```

This is what is in to-url-test.js:

```
import {
  toUrl
} from 'new-cms/helpers/to-url';

module('ToUrlHelper');

// Replace this with your real tests.
test('it works', function() {
  var result = toUrl(42);
  ok(result);
});
```

Code from the actual helper:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(value) {
    if(typeof(value) !== 'undefined') {
        return value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    }
    return '';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is nothing but you're passing 42 to your function and then trying to apply `.replace` function on it. But this function is only defined on string...

Start by passing in a string like "hello me" instead of 42, then pass 42 in another test, see your test break because your implementation does not take this into account and fix your implementation. (This is kinda Test Driven Development)

Comment: I'm using the ember-cli and it generated the test so I'm not sure why the number '42' is being passed. Should I just delete the test and recreate it using the cli?

Comment: Well, I guess Ember cli simply generated a basic test for you without knowing the implementation of your function. Your test is supposed to "validate" the expected behavour. In your toUrl function, you don't expect to received numbers, but rather strings. Then your test must validate unexpected but "might happen" behavour, thus you should test to pass null, undefined, a number, etc... to your function and modify its implementation to avoid its breaking. (That's actually exactly what happened here, ember cli provided an edge case and broke your code).

Comment: if this answers your question, please do check it as the correct answer. This will validate it.